# Как обновить данные в таблице из другой с выборкой?

Tags: mysql, sql, update

Есть две таблицы с одинаковыми полями:

Table1:

```
id | catId | title | status
```

Table2

```
id | catId | title | status | desc
```

Как возможно обновить столбец `status` в Table2 из такого же в Table1 для записей, где совпадает `catId`?

Что-то вроде

```
UPDATE
    Table2
SET
   Table2.status = Table1.status
   
FROM
   Table1 
WHERE
    Table2.catId = Table1.catId;
```

Естественно, не работают. А join-запросы мне пока не очень то поддаются.

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующий SQL.

Для справки: [MySQL UPDATE: Top 5 Tips for T-SQL Developers](https://codingsight.com/mysql-update-top-5-tips-for-t-sql-developers/)

**SQL**

```
UPDATE Table2 a
INNER JOIN Table1 b ON a.catId = b.catId
SET status = b.status;
```